# how to display this chinese character?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, cjk

I already set mySQL Collation as utf8_unicode_ci, if I manual insert chinese character in my database, it's successful work to displaying chinese character, but once i use my code, it was display this

ã€å¼µç‘žæŒ¯ã€æ±Ÿç¥¥ç¶�..

I had add this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>` in my header, I had try utf8_encode ,but still the same problem happen.

thank you and hope you guy reply me soonest

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the connection character set / collation? Execute this query immediately after creating a connection

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgot to execute this query after connecting

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Try it and you'll see

Comment: Pretty sure the `charset_name` should be quoted. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: @Phil: not, it can, but isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

there 2 steps you should do

1. add a query with UTF8

   `$query = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";`

   `mysql_query($query);`
2. make sure your file is encoded as UTF8, 
   open your script with your favourite editor and save as UTF8

Comment: I guess your file does not have to be encoded as UTF8, since in the file itself are no UTF characters at all.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure MySQL expects UTF-8 encoding by default from client connections, use the following query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

In addition, make sure PHP interprets the string as UTF-8 string. Since PHP does not support multibyte characters, you must use a function to allow PHP to work with UTF-8 strings:

```
utf8_decode()
```

or something.